# Compiling for win8 32bit with visual studio 2012

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012, compilation, 32-bit

I have project I've made in visual studio that contains an executable and dll which it calls.  Everything works fine when I build them for the 64 bit machine I have visual studio on, but when I change the platform to Win32 compile the executable and dll and attempt to run it on my win8 32 bit machines I get the following error two messages on (two different machines):

> The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your
>   computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

and:

> The procedure entry point
>   ?in@?$codecvt@DDH@std@@QBEHAAHPBD1AAPBDPAD3AAPAD@2 could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: Thanks, that got everything working.